# Closing a thread if its open after 10 seconds

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have a thread I start like this:

```
Dim documentConverterThread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf ConvertToLatestVersion)

documentConverterThread.Start(oDoc)
```

And this is the function the word document is passed to:

```
  Private Sub ConvertWordTemplateToLatestVersion(ByVal oDoc As Word.Document)
    Try
      oDoc.Convert()
      oDoc.Save()
      oDoc.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
  End Sub
```

What I'm trying to do is that if execution gets stuck when calling the .Convert() function, then close the thread and the word document.

I have been trying to use a timer, but I need access to both the documentConverterThread and oDoc objects to handle the Timer.Tick event:

```
  Private Sub TimerEventProcesser(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If documentConverterThread.IsAlive() Then
      documentConverterThread.Abort()
      oDoc.Close()        
    End If
  End Sub
```

Is there any way around this other than using a private variable in the TimerEventProcessor function? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create another thread for it. Using the `Sub()` lambda you can create an inline delegate from which you can call the new timer method and pass both the thread variable and the document variable to it. The new thread will then wait 10 seconds, and if the first thread isn't finished it will close the document.

```
Private Sub ConvertWordTemplateToLatestVersion(ByVal oDoc As Word.Document)
    Dim TimerThread As New Threading.Thread(Sub() TimerThread(documentConverterThread, oDoc))
    TimerThread.Start() 'Start the timer thread.

    Try
      oDoc.Convert()
      oDoc.Save()
      oDoc.Close()
    Catch 'Why catch an exception if we do not even handle it?
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub TimerThread(ByRef dcThread As Threading.Thread, ByRef oDoc As Word.Document)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000) 'Wait 10 seconds.
    If dcThread.IsAlive() Then 'Close the document if the primary thread isn't finished yet.
        dcThread.Abort()
        Try
            oDoc.Close()
            oDoc.Dispose()
        Catch
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

I used `ByRef` instead of `ByVal` to be sure we are referencing the same objects all the time and not newly created ones.

Comment: @cjw : Woah, that was fast. Did you even get to try it? ;)

Comment: I wasn't aware that As Action() existed, thank you. And I definitely want ByRef as well, good catch.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need, checking  it now

Comment: @cjw : Please tell me you target .NET Framework 4.0 or higher?

Comment: @cjw : Good, because to make this simple you require at least that. Now, see my new edit. It should solve it for you. It uses a lambda expression to create a delegate. I have tested it now and it should work, sorry for the confusion. :)